# Plot using 3 variables in matplotlib with condition

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Hi I have data like below.

[image: sample code]

I need to write a code dynamically to input my year and make a plot between month and number of messages. The year 2016 in my data has only 6 months and rest doesn't exist.

I tried setting year as index and tried plotting.

```
dff[dff.index == 2015].plot(marker='*')
```

But the plot I did is not what is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) or [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) for filtering and then [`plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) with parameters `x` and `y`:

```
year = 2014

df[df['year'] == year].plot(x='month', y='Number of messages', marker='*')
```

Or:

```
df.query("year == @year").plot(x='month', y='Number of messages', marker='*')
```

Another approach is plot `Series` with index by `Month` column:

```
df = df.set_index('month')
df.loc[df['year'] == year, 'Number of messages'].plot(marker='*')
```

---

```
df.set_index('month').query("year == @year")['Number of messages'].plot(marker='*')
```